# Show All Native iOS Dependencies/Frameworks for an Xcode Project That Uses Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I know this has to be relatively simple but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get an answer.

Back in the old days when I would integrate 3rd party SDKs manually I could just check the `Link Binary With Libraries` section of Xcode's `Build Phases` to see all the libraries/frameworks that my project was including.

I use Cocoapods mostly now. Sometimes I'm only integrating 3rd party SDKs with Cocoapods, and sometimes I'll do some through Cocoapods but then have to manually integrate one or two.

How can I determine what Native (i.e. `AdSupport.framework`, `QuartzCore.framework`, etc.) frameworks/libraries my project will link against when using Cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap on your Pods project in Xcode. Then tapping on each target you can see each of 'Link Binary with Libraries' setting in Build Phases.

Comment: I'm noticing that some pods do not have a corresponding Target in the Pods project. Can I safely assume they do not have any native dependencies in that case?

Comment: No, I don't think that's necessarily the case. If I look at Crashlytics for example then its podspec lists Security and SystemConfiguration as frameworks it depends on but Crashlytics does not show as a Target in my Pods project.

Comment: Where are you looking to see that Crashlytics requires Security/SystemConfiguration? I've it in my project too if you want to just use it as a reference

Comment: See here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/3/6/0/Crashlytics/3.12.0/Crashlytics.podspec.json